# How to solve broken FEP

Tags: troubleshooting, resin, repair

I have a Creality LD-006 resin printer and my FEP breaks very often. When I'm printing I heard a hard "tac¨" (it's because the cured resin is taking of the FEP when the printing bed goes up).

I'm using a Creality standard resin white with 2.7 exposure time.

This is how my FEP breaks (I replaced the FEP (it was original) and made maybe 2 or 3 prints and it broke).

[image: Broken FEP]

Could it be that I'm printing a lot of small pieces at once?

I have a smaller printer (Creality Halot-One) and I made more prints and I never have this type of problem. Maybe I can't print small pieces in a big printer?

Comment: Note for other readers: A 'hard tac" is a French onomatopoeia for a "loud cracking sound"

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Just to clarify, the FEP is a film (not a filament)? The exposure time is in what unit of time, seconds, minutes? Presumably seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### FEPs are consumables

Once an FEP film on the foil has developed cracking, it's a lost cause and has to be replaced in due time - repair to pre-damage conditions is impossible even if you manufacture them.

You can try to avoid the affected areas and eek a few more prints out of the film, but the damage will spread and make the film unusable in the longer term.

### Damage to FEP can occur due to bad resin

If your resin contains *any* chunks due to print failure, those can result in damage of the FEP.

### Bad Placement and high speed can damage FEPS

Another reason can be too pointed pressure, which happens for example if the only spot is pulling up very high, and then suddenly releases.

The position of the printed objects can be as much the factor in this case as the size or geometry of the release area.

The more controllable factors that play into this are the lifting speed and height of the bed. It takes some non-zero amount of time for the film to release the model. During this time the film adheres to the model, and can be simulated as a spring. The force of a spring is dependent on a constant and its elongation: $F=k \times \Delta d(t) $. Our foil would have a variable factor $k$, dependent on the coordinate in the vat. However, for us, the elongation at the moment t $\Delta d(t)$ is relevant. By lifting faster and higher, the film is experiencing more elongation (stretch) and a sharper release from the model happens. Higher stress means damage to the film.

Comment: If the lifting speed is quite fast could this lead to this types of problems rigth?

Comment: it might... indeed, lower lifting speed *might* reduce the stress as forces should be lower...